# setting windows live messenger nick and status message using win32com.client

Tags: python, windows, live, windows-live-messenger

is their any way to set windows live messenger using the win32com library ?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wlmessengerapidev/thread/f0b08334-883a-42b9-b79c-8f1f899e65d6) at MSDN forum discusses the topic thoroughly.

In short, you can do it with [this API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd570146.aspx)

Another possibility is to use a python based web client to do it over http at home.live.com